# Image inside Scrollview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am new to iPhone,

I want to do scrolling in my image which is inside scrollView but i am unable to scroll my image,

Here is my code snippet,

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"768bg_with_footer.gif"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
scrollView.contentSize = image1.size;
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
```

I have taken ScrollView in my `.xib` file.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"768bg_with_footer.gif"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
scrollView.contentSize = image1.size;
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
```

We use `initWithContentsOfFile` when we know the `path` of the image.Using it with imageName will give a null image.

Comment: `NSString* bg = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"768bg_with_footer.gif"];
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:bg];
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;` i tried this also.

Comment: Put this code in your ViewDidLoad :  NSString* bg = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"768bg_with_footer.gif"];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:bg];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
    [self.scrollVw addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.scrollVw.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width+100, image1.size.height+100);

Comment: Please take realtime conversations to chat.

Comment: I'm purging the remaining comments soon, please put anything you want to retain into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try following instead

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
```